# Jumping Cursor using the contenteditable-Tag in a webview on Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, html, webview, cursor, contenteditable

1. create a webview and put in following html-code

`<p contenteditable="true">
  Very long text
 </p>`

1. Put some long text into the p-tag, so it becomes scrollable
2. select the first line of the text by tapping into the p-tag
3. scoll down till the cursor is not visible anymore
4. try to position the cursor into the text by tapping
5. the cursor will jump to a wrong position

Hints:

1. This happens only on Android 4.4.4. On other OS the cursor jumps to the position you tapped on
2. This problem only occurs when the cursor is out of the display. Everything works fine if the cursor remains visible after scrolling

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Please look at this. You get some ideas.

http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=GeneralB&messageId=215282

Comment: The link is broken, please update it or update your answer with the contents of what the link used to have.